# I want to show some function as the norm of two vectors.

Tags: functional-analysis, machine-learning

I want to see $[\sin(x-y)]^2$ is rewritten by the square of the norm of the difference of two vectors like following (It is a sample and it's not right).
$$
\| (\sin(x) , \cos(x) \sin(x) ) - (\sin(y) , \cos(y) \sin(y) )\|
$$
Please tell me how to consider this problem ...

- It is the problem 6.6 of Foundations of Machine Leraning (Mohri etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\frac{1}{2}(\sin 2x, \cos 2x)$ and $v=\frac{1}{2}(\sin 2y , \cos 2y)$. Then
\begin{align*}
2(u-v)&=(\sin 2x-\sin 2y, \cos 2x-\cos 2y)\\
4\|u-v\|^2&=(\sin 2x-\sin 2y)^2+ (\cos 2x-\cos 2y)^2\\
&=2-2(\sin 2x\sin 2y+\cos 2x\cos 2y)\\
&=2-2\cos(2x-2y)\\
&=2 (1-\cos(2x-2y))\\
&=4 \sin^2(x-y)\\
\|u-v\|^2&=\sin^2(x-y)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!  How do you come up with this idea?...

Comment: @Nao Think about unit circle with center $O$ and two points $P(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and $Q(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$ on that circle. The distance $PQ$ will be given in terms of the sine of the $\angle POQ=\theta-\alpha$.